# Combine default Props styles with inline Styles

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx

I have a component like this

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div
                style={{...styles.container, ...this.props.containerStyles}} />
            <div 
                style={{...styles.headline, ...this.props.headlineStyles}} />
        )
    };
};

const styles = {
    container: {
        width: '50px'
        height: '60px',
    },
    headline: {
        color: 'red',
};

SomeComponent.defaultProps = {
    backgroundColor = 'grey',
    overflow: 'hidden',
    fontSize: 20,
};
```

I wonder how can I combine `styles.container` with `this.props.containerStyles` and `defaultProps`? Imagine in `this.props.containerStyles` is only the `backgroundColor`, but not the `overflow`. I would want the `overflow: hidden` from the `defaultProps`. On the otherside, if there is nothing passed through `this.props.containerStyles` I want all the `defaultProps`.  In any case, `styles.container` shall always be applied.

Is there a way to do that with `defaultProps` or do I have to use `JavaScript` logic, like (pseudo Code)

```
 let fancyStyleObj = {};
 if(this.props.containerStyles.backgroundColor) {
     fancyStyleObj.backgroundColor = this.props.containerStyles.backgroundColor 
 } else { 
     fancyStyleObj.backgroundColor = 'grey'
 }
```

However, that would bypass `defaultProps` as I would have to write the `defaultProps` into the `else` clause.

Comment: As per your statement you want `defaultProps` optional, if there is `containerStyles` is available and `styles.container` must be applied. Is my understading right ?

Comment: @Revansiddh Nearly. I want every entry from `defaultProps` to be optionally. If `containerStyles` only supplies `backgroundColor`, I still need the `overflow: hidden` from `defaultProps`.

Comment: `style={[{...defaultProps },{...this.props.containerStyles },styles.container]}` I hope this will hope. This will overide/combine all properties from left to righ. Support `defaultProps` and `containerStyles` have same properties then it will select  props value of `containerStyles` same with `styles.container`. will combine all props if none of them have common

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is correct, but you are doing mistake here:

```
SomeComponent.defaultProps = {
    backgroundColor = 'grey',
    overflow: 'hidden',
};
```

By this way, backgroundColor and overflow will be available inside `this.props`, not in `this.props.containerStyles`. Define the values inside `containerStyles`.

Write it like this:

```
SomeComponent.defaultProps = {
  containerStyles: {
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
    overflow: 'hidden',
  }
};
```

Or use:

```
style={{ ...styles.container, ...this.props }}
```

Working Example (with `this.props.containerStyles`):

```js
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        style={{ ...styles.container, ...this.props.containerStyles }}>
        hello
      </div>
    )
  };
};

const styles = {
  container: {
    width: '50px',
    height: '60px',
  },
};

SomeComponent.defaultProps = {
  containerStyles: {
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
    overflow: 'hidden',
  }
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<SomeComponent />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='root' />
```

Working example (with `this.props`):

```js
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        style={{ ...styles.container, ...this.props }}>
        hello
      </div>
    )
  };
};

const styles = {
  container: {
    width: '50px',
    height: '60px',
  },
};

SomeComponent.defaultProps = {
  backgroundColor: 'grey',
  overflow: 'hidden',
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<SomeComponent />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='root' />
```

Comment: Hm, when I do not supply `overflow: hidden` in `this.props.containerStyles` it is not added through `defaultProps` to the `div`.

Comment: use the second approach, because defaultProps will be assigned only when the key will not be present in `props`, it will not merge two object, since you are passing the containerStyles key in props, so no default value will be passed to component for `containerStyles` (means the object passed from parent will not be merged with defaultProps)

Comment: I fear the second approach won't work when I have several external styles like `this.props.containerStyles, this.props.headlineStyles, this.props.textStyles, ...` in the same `SomeComponent`, but different `div` tags?

Comment: yup that's true, in that case we can do one more thing, instead of using the defaultProps, use normal const variables for styling and merge those objects.

Comment: I understand. Thanks

Comment: something like this, [**Example**](https://codesandbox.io/s/kkm5qko4w5), hoping you will get the idea :)